# React.js recipe for large incremental list of items rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The task is very simple: I have a `<List />` of items (each - small React Component), and, for example, from 10 to 30 (non-evenly) new items per second appending to that list - with total count about 250-500 (which is not so large at all) - ideally, with some animation on append. If I do it in vanilla JS, I get much better performance then in React (suppose because of calculating new virtual DOM 10-30 times per second). Is there a conform way to improve React performance in this task? I tried some `shouldComponentUpdate` workaround, but that still does not work fine. I also know there some "hacks" like `<InfiniteList />` and `<VirtualList />`, but I doubt about its' flexibility.
Or is this limit natural?

Comment: Have you tried batching the updates? Even updating only once a second (with everything that came in in the last second) could make a big difference, and the user wouldn't be able to tell much of a difference. Some code to look at would really help.

Comment: Yes, I even implemented a simple [`<BatchedList />`](https://gist.github.com/soylent-grin/222a6442d414f8c91545) component - but still got interface freeze on re-render because of React (or Redux? - should measure) calculation overhead, that grows according to current number of items.

Comment: That really shouldn't happen. `shouldComponentUpdate` should keep processing down to only the items being updated. [This guy](https://aerotwist.com/blog/react-plus-performance-equals-what/) shows some detailed tests confirming this. It's *possible* you're reducers are adding overhead per-item, but that should be pretty small. Have you combined `shouldComponentUpdate` with batching?

Answer (score 0):

You could cache your list and only update say every 50 new items.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook recently released [FixedTableData](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/), which has support for lazy rendering and virtualization.

Comment: Saw it, but  I look for some general recipe - where `<List />` can be, for example, container for material design like cards.